# Laravel 5.5 Redis problem - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connect()

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5.5, predis, phpredis

I moved my Laravel 5.5 application to another server - I use exactly the same code there (did a `git clone`) with exactly the same `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files (even the `NGINX` configuration is the same).

When I run my application I get the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connect()
```

Here is the code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
public function somefunction() {
    $redis = new \Redis();
    $redis->connect(env('REDIS_HOST')); <-------------
...
```

The composer package `predis/predis` is installed and I have no `php-redis` on my system.

On both systems (debian) redis is installed and runs on `127.0.0.1`. Both systems use the same configuration in `.env` and in `config/*`:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

The only thing, which is different is, that on one system (old one) I'm runnning `php7.0` and on the new system I run `php7.3` - I switched to `php7.0` on the new system to check if that's the error, but I still get the exception.

Once again - on my other server everything is running fine with exactly the same code, which frustrates me - I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have "cluster" (if it exists there) set to "false" in the Redis configuration?

Comment: Try "connection" instead of "connect". See `$redis->connection(env('REDIS_HOST')); `

Comment: Yes, `connection` works. I fugured that out already, but why? Also I don't want to change the code.

Comment: Because You get a Redis instance by calling the `Redis::connection();` method.
This will give you an instance of the default Redis server. You may also pass the connection or cluster name to the connection method to get a specific server or cluster as defined in your Redis configuration

Comment: Why is it working on another system then with the same code and `connect()`? It does not work, becauase if you change it to `connection()` you will get strange syntax errors in the `predis/predis` core files, which is weird.

Comment: phpredis is a native extension, it's bound to be more efficient than predis even if the development is less active. So its better to use in my recommendation. Also lets try pconnect() as it might be possible that once your connection persisted and now it isn't. It checks and connect if your connection was once established

Comment: You are using Predis and then you write `$redis = new \Redis();`, then ofcourse it will go for redis' methods to work and not predis'. Try to add 
`require('./Predis.php');
$redis   = new Predis\Client('redis://$z');
$redis->connect();`
predis has `connect()` while for redis its `connection()`

Comment: @JitendraAhuja - you are absolutely right! I messed up stuff in my hurry. I was thinking I was using the predis extension all the time. Man, thank you so much for your efforts and time! I made a big mistake, was and still is a very stressful day. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Oh thats absolutely fine ! Happy to help you my friend :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these are some basic steps you need to check :

1) Firstly, make sure you have phpredis PHP extension installed

2) If you have cluster in your redis configuration, then make sure to set it to false : see

`'cluster' => false,`

3) Try to check that Redis server is working and redis client is able to connect with it. Some times redis server is crashed or closed unexpectedly then you may have to restart or shutdown them and work again.

4) If you're running in a *nix environment, you can check the netstat output to see if Redis is listening on whatever port (say 6379) you have it configured to listen on:

`netstat -na | grep 6379`

You should see output like this if it's listening:

`tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:6379 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:53760 127.0.0.1:6379 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:6379 127.0.0.1:48107 ESTABLISHED
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:53758 127.0.0.1:6379 TIME_WAIT
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:48107 127.0.0.1:6379 ESTABLISHED`

5) in app/config/cache.php, set the driver to redis:

`'driver' => 'redis'`

6) Try using redis as the driver in app/config/session.php:

`'driver' => 'redis'`

7) add the following at the top of your source:

`use Illuminate\Redis\Database as Redis;`

or

`"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis"`

8) Try Changing the class alias to RedisL4 in app/config/app.php like

`'RedisL4' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',`

and then using this code probably solves the problem:

`$redis = RedisL4::connect();` or more importantly its "connection" and not "connect" so

`$redis = RedisL4::connection(Your-Connection-Here);`

Comment: It does not help unfortunately. Regarding point 1: I'm using predis/predis instead of phpredis.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are passing the **REDIS_CLIENT** properly.

For me, I had installed [predis](https://packagist.org/packages/predis/predis) via composer, but REDIS_CLIENT was set to [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).

I had to change **REDIS_CLIENT** to **predis** in my database.php / .env file.

REDIS_CLIENT=predis